# How to disable swipeback gestures in Blazor PWA on iOS

Tags: c#, ios, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I've created a Blazor WASM SPA PWA to be used on iPhones. Even when the app is added to the Homescreen it's possible to navigate to the previous page of the application by a swipe gesture moving left to right.
As this may break my application logic I'm looking for a way to disable this navigation gesture.
But up to now I did not find any possiblity...

I've tried to modify MainLayout.razor to prevent this:

```
<div class="page" @ontouchmove:preventDefault="true">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <NavMenu />
    </div>
```

but it seems to have no effect

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.